# How should we celebrate reaching 100,000 questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-statistics

We currently have over 99,000 questions asked.  I think we should celebrate when we reach the 100,000 mark.

Comment: That's a neat idea @AndreSilva.

Comment: We have reached 99,250 questions on CV.  At this pace I think we will reach 100,000 questions sometime on Monday April 3rd.

Comment: As the comments below suggest, even something as simple as defining 100,000 questions is rubbery and inexact:  questions are deleted, removed etc.

Comment: In stock markets there's a measure called session high, we can use the same concept: the celebration happens on the day during which at any time the questions count hit 100k

Comment: @MichaelChernick, it is taking longer than you indicated. It is about 9 days since your comment, while your forecast was roughly 4.5 days. Let us see how much longer we need to wait.

Comment: @RichardHardy My first guess was based on naive understanding of how the question number was defined.  After my latest projection the total fell back under 99,800. I still think it will be within the next two or three days.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, wow, it is down to 99,715... We are facing a countdown here.

Comment: @MichaelChernick, up at 99,957 -- looks promising :)

Comment: I'm going to celebrate myself tonight

Comment: Sounds good Aksakal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about Sydney, Australia. Do we have enough people to sit for a coffee gather up?

Comment: Many of us are in the United States and probably would not be able to makes the trip to Australia especially since the day will come within the next few days. There is really no time to book the trip.

Comment: We should start planning 200K in Australia.

Comment: There are a few Sydneysiders about the site, so it might be worth considering doing something small for the 100K; if not on the day then perhaps during the ensuing days

Comment: @Glen_b Good. How should we organise it?

Comment: @Small I'd suggest that at this stage (since the site will probably hit it something like Friday night Zulu time, which would be Saturday for you) you should just nominate a convenient time and place for you (or suggest a couple of possibilities if you prefer) and see if anyone says they'd come (or suggests an alternative). You may not get any takers at this stage but it's probably worth trying either for the weekend or during next week. You could always make a chat room if you want to be able to negotiate places/times.

Comment: It is 8 PM EDT from 8 PM yesterday to 8 PM today the number of questions increased from 99,700 to 99, 803. At this rate we should hit 100,000 in a little less than two days.

Comment: We lost about 200 questions so far today.  Maybe we will have to wait a little longer.

Comment: An idea: if you run out of time to organize the event, then just go through open questions looking for those to be closed, that would buy you a few more days :)

Comment: We just passed 99,900 for the first time.

Comment: @MichaelChernick If the US people decide to meet. I will start a new post to check any interest for Sydney, Australia.

Comment: @Aksaka Why do you want to delay it?  Many of us vote to close open questions that seem to fail the requirements of the site but we don't do it just to keep the number of open questions from increasing.

Comment: @SmallChess, US people cherish their privacy, and don't want to see each other

Comment: @Aksakal I don't think I can do it in Australia then... I don't care my privacy because I don't have it.

Comment: @SmallChess, why don't you start an answer with your place of choice? who knows maybe there are folks in the area willing to smoke and drink

Comment: We are now only 21 questions short of 100,000.

Comment: We just reached 100,000 questions! I am not sure that it will last.

Comment: Take a look at amoeba's link that captures the moment on the question about celebrating 100,000 questions in Australia SmallChess.

Answer (score 13):

We can hold the local meetups with whiskey and cigars. Maybe folks with high reputation points cluster around a few places, so it shouldn't be very difficult to organize. We can set to T+1 date and agree on the local places.

I wonder if there's any easy way to analyze geo clustering of users with high rep points.

Update. Given the contribution of Gosset to the field, maybe beer themed meetup would be appropriate too. I'm sure there's Guinness serving bar in any locality

Comment: I know some of us are located in the Philadelphia area.

Comment: Yeap. That would be nice!

Comment: Whiskey and cigars? Not the most diplomatic choice, even suggested flippantly! Different but not negligible fractions of people here are likely to be appalled by one or the other or even both.

Comment: @NickCox in no way my suggestion was meant to be inclusive, yet participants aren't required to have unhealthy habits: carrot juice and kale are in ample supply across the country.

Comment: Hah! Now there's a presumption on a strongly international forum that just one country is involved. Don't give up the day job for diplomacy. Insert smileys to some large power.

Comment: @NickCox: Or appalled by neither individually, but by the combination.

Comment: @Scortchi At the end of the meeting people could award the R.A. Fisher prize for obstinate use of tobacco in the face of statistical evidence. (Sorry, if it's in Philadelphia, I can't be there.)

Comment: There are less than 500 questions to go to reach the 100,000 number!

Comment: @MichaelChernick, then we got to hurry up. it's harder to reserve seats in bars in the 2nd half of the week! that's assuming that the celebrations are in non-prohibitive geographies

Comment: @NickCox, the [latest research](http://www.npr.org/sections/health-shots/2017/03/23/521219318/cancer-is-partly-caused-by-bad-luck-study-finds) indicates that smoking hazard function is greatly overestimated: most cancer is caused by random mutation which have nothing to do with behavioral or environmental factors! It's just the sample size is so large that eventually everyone gets the bad luck mutation and dies

Comment: I am old enough to remember when it was greatly underestimated, just after many doctors recommended smoking as good for you. So, I don't change my attitudes to follow the latest twist in the wind.

Comment: @NickCox and Aksakal: **NOPE:** Tomasetti and Vogelstein fell *profoundly* afoul of the atomistic fallacy. See for example, Sornette, D. and Favre, M. (2015). [Debunking mathematically the logical fallacy that cancer risk is just “bad luck”](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1140/epjnbp/s40366-015-0026-0). *EPJ Nonlinear Biomedical Physics*, 3(10):1–6. **Aside:** *Science* is generally not where epidemiologists publish major findings.

Comment: @Alexis that's an old paper. I'm referring to a new one

Comment: Who is in the Portland, Oregon area? :)

Comment: @Alexis pretty amazing considering that the paper I refer to was published in 2017 and yours is fon 2015

Comment: Aw gosh, I see now that is a more recent paper by the same authors. Looks interesting, too. More nuanced.

Comment: @Alexis Also it was observed that [years of Smoking Associated with Lower Parkinson’s Risk](https://www.aan.com/PressRoom/Home/PressRelease/813)