# Celebrate 100,000 questions in Sydney, Australia?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-statistics

> [How should we celebrate reaching 100,000 questions?](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4706/how-should-we-celebrate-reaching-100-000-questions)

I'm not sure this'd even work... But let's see.

I nominate **22nd April Saturday, 3pm** gather for coffee breaks in Sydney CBD.

Let's me briefly describe myself:

My background is in computing, finance and mathematics. I'm currently a bioinformatician, specalized in genomic analysis. I use statistics to develop models for our DNA genome.

I used to work as a quantitative analyst in finance, where I helped developing option pricing models. But I find statistics more interesting.

I'd argue myself an expert in chess programming. I write my own chess engines and sell them for profits on mobile platform (http://www.smallchess.com). I'm currently the leader in chess engine on [chess.stackexchange.com](http://chess.stackexchange.com) by a wide margin (2x the second leader):

> https://chess.stackexchange.com/tags/engines/topusers

I'm applying statistics and machine learning in chess. I don't just use save statistics R-code somewhere on Github. I'd actually translate the code into C++, and **sell it** on the App Store.

Let's run through two example I'm still working on:

**Q1: What's the piece value for a given chess position?**

Chess players use their experience to say which chess pieces are "good", and which chess pieces are "bad". Imagine there is a mobile app that you can download from the App Store, where you give it a chess position and it tells you statistical value for each piece? What about the Monte Carlo tree search? Maybe we can use logistic regression?

[image]

**Q2: How to derive similarity measure for two different chess positions?**

This is actually an insane problem. The positions must have similar evaluation to be considered similar. Unfortunately, there is no known way to do it without running a chess engine. Running a chess engine is very slow, we would like to do it statically. Imagine there is a reliable similarity measure, we'd be able to apply machine learning on a given position, and compare it to a set of pre-trained models.

We can talk about anything interesting related to data analytics and chess!

**EDIT (we have two):**

I have got a taker. So we have two (including myself). More!

**EDIT**

Bump up the page.

Comment: 22th, eh? When you say "leader in chess engine" you mean you lead in reputation on the tag `engines`?

Comment: @Glen_b Anything wrong with 22th? Yes. I spent most of time on chess.

Comment: How do you pronounce "22th"? :) Twenty secondth?

Comment: @amoeba: "Twenty tooth"

Comment: I think I'm out of the loop, but what's the purpose of these threads? Completely lost on this one.

Comment: @Firebug https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4706/how-should-we-celebrate-reaching-100-000-questions

Comment: Oh yeah, saw that one earlier too (even commented on one answer), but most answers/comments don't seem serious, I thought I was loosing some inside joke or something like that.

Comment: @Firebug I'm not sure it'll work, but nothing to lose.

Comment: I wish I could come with the total at 99,965 currently, the first time past 100,000 might be today April 11th.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Yeah. Best time for posting.

Comment: We just reached 100,000 questions.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I made a screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/95Jy4MR.png

Comment: @amoeba That ia very nice and very clever!

Comment: @amoeba, there's no timestamp in the screenshot

Comment: @Aksakal Yeah, too bad. But my comment has a timestamp (mouseover "yesterday"). And Imgur has timestamp too: http://imgur.com/95Jy4MR (mouseover "1d").

Comment: At over 100,500 questions now (April 19th) maybe we will be close to 101 K by April 22nd.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Alex came. A prominent statistician who wished to remain anonymous also attended. We talked about statistics and many other things.

Thanks everybody!

Comment: That sounds great! I am very glad that you were able to organize a nice informal meeting over this.

Comment: Americans are worried too much about their privacy to meet in person :)

Answer (score 4):

Coincidentally, it happens that March for Science is happening worldwide on this date. The Sydney event is finishes just prior to your coffee date :)

https://marchforscienceaustralia.org/sydney/

Comment: U can join us! Come!

Comment: Where will you be, exactly?

Comment: Email tedwong@smallchess.com we can talk

Comment: We will be in city please join! Town hall

Comment: After the event please let us know how it goes. It is April 21st and we are at 100,634 questions.

Comment: @MichaelChernick We met and it was fun.

Comment: This event is too political for my taste. The last thing we want is to alienate general population. People are already weary of all these folks who claim to be scientists. This will be hijacked by activists inevitably again.

Comment: @Aksakal Agreed. I did wear my [Science. It works, bitches.](https://xkcd.com/54/) xkcd t-shirt today, but I did not join the march.

Comment: First they came for the Socialists, and I did not speak out...